# LibGDX - OpenGL Exception on android caused by Texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am experiencing a strange problem with LibGDX, when i want to run android apptication.
I am running it on Samsung Galaxy SII.

Here is the **main part**

```
package com.android.app;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;


public class App extends Game{

private static TextureAtlas atlas;

@Override
    public void create() {
        new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/textures1.png"));
    }
}
```

Here is **android part**

```
package com.android.app;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;

public class AndroidApp extends AndroidApplication {
        public void onCreate (android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                initialize(new App(), true);
                //It crasher even if OpenGL-ES 2.0 is not used
        }
}
```

I'll get this error

> OpenGL 2.0 not used

```
Thread [<12> GLThread] (Suspended (exception GdxRuntimeException))  
GLSurfaceViewCupcake$GLThread.run() line: 650
```

> OpenGL 2.0 is used

```
Thread [<9> GLThread 10] (Suspended (exception GdxRuntimeException))    
       GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run() line: 1142
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: There should be more detail in the GdxRuntimeException.  What is the exact log output you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just **changed**

```
new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/textures1.png"));
```

**to**

```
 new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("textures1.png"));
```